# requiredfieldvalidator clashing with formview

Tags: c#, asp.net

can anyone help me with out ? When i put requiredfieldvalidator on my create event's tabcontainer, i cannot update my formview which is on another tab >>> edit event's tab.
I have totally no idea what happen, and as i trial and error, i found that the requiredfieldvalidator is the one that cause my formview to stop updating into my database. AND i this requiredfieldvalidator is on another tab, so how did it affect ?!?!?
Please be specified or show e.g as I am REALLY REALLY NEW AND BAD !

Here is the code for create tab >>>

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="tb_eventName" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="tb_eventName" ErrorMessage="Enter event" 
                    ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="vg" SetFocusOnError="True" >*        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        <asp:Button ID="bn_createEvent" runat="server"  
                    Text="Create Event" onclick="bn_createEvent_Click"    ValidationGroup="vg"/>`
```

Here is the code for edit event tab >>>

```
        <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="eventID" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
                    OnItemDeleted="FormView1_ItemDeleted"   OnItemInserted="FormView1_ItemInserted" 
                    OnItemUpdated="FormView1_ItemUpdated" ForeColor="Black"   BackColor="White" 
                    BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
                    GridLines="Vertical" >
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        ID:
                        <asp:Label ID="eventIDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%#   Eval("eventID") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        Name:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                        <asp:TextBox ID="eventNameTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("eventName") %>' />
                        &nbsp&nbsp
                        <br />
                        <br />


                        Date:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                        <asp:TextBox ID="eventDateTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("eventDate") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <br />

                        Start-Time:&nbsp
                        <asp:TextBox ID="eventStartTimeTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("eventStartTime") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <br />

                        End-Time:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                        <asp:TextBox ID="eventEndTimeTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("eventEndTime") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <br />

                        Location:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                        <asp:TextBox ID="eventLocationTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("eventLocation") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <br />

                        Email:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                        <asp:TextBox ID="eventEmailTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("eventEmail") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <br />

                        Contact No:&nbsp
                        <asp:TextBox ID="eventContactNoTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("eventContactNo") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <br />

                        Description:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="eventDescriptionTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("eventDescription") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <br />

                        Image:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                        <asp:TextBox ID="eventImageTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("eventImage") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <br />

                        <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" 
                            CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
```

`

After adding requiredfieldvalidator it doesnt update my formview to database

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `ValidationGroup` to the button in the FormView. Make sure that you use a different  group name compared to the required field validator that is causing the formview update to fail.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server"
    CommandName="Update" Text="Update"
    ValidationGroup="formViewValidation" />
```

That should make it so that the req. field validator for the `vg` is not triggered when clicking button Update.

**Edit**: Just to check. What happens if you add `CausesValidation="False"` on the Update button?

Comment: I have been playing with all these behaviours, nth really happened, still did not work ;/ pls help